# Bounding box detection for characters / digits

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I have images, which look like the following:

[image]

I want to find the bounding boxes for the 8 digits. My first try was to use cv2 with the following code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox

im = cv2.imread('31197402.png')
bbox, label, conf = cv.detect_common_objects(im)
output_image = draw_bbox(im, bbox, label, conf)
plt.imshow(output_image)
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem in your solution is likely the input image, which is very poor in quality. There’s hardly any contrast between the characters and the background. The blob detection algorithm from `cvlib` is probably failing to distinguish between character blobs and background, producing a useless binary mask. Let’s try to solve this using purely `OpenCV`.

I propose the following steps:

1. Apply **adaptive threshold** to get a reasonably good binary mask.
2. Clean the binary mask from blob noise using an **area filter**.
3. Improve the quality of the binary image using **morphology**.
4. Get the outer **contours** of each character and fit a **bounding rectangle** to each character blob.
5. **Crop** each character using the previously calculated bounding rectangle.

Let’s see the code:

```
# importing cv2 & numpy:
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Set image path
path = "C:/opencvImages/"
fileName = "mrrm9.png"

# Read input image:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path+fileName)
inputCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Convert BGR to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

From here there’s not much to discuss, just reading the `BGR` image and converting it to `grayscale`. Now, let’s apply an `adaptive threshold` using the `gaussian` method. This is the tricky part, as the parameters are adjusted manually depending on the quality of the input. The way the method works is dividing the image into a grid of cells of `windowSize`, it then applies a local threshold to found the optimal separation between foreground and background. An additional constant, indicated by `windowConstant` can be added to the threshold to fine tune the output:

```
# Set the adaptive thresholding (gasussian) parameters:
windowSize = 31
windowConstant = -1
# Apply the threshold:
binaryImage = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(grayscaleImage, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, windowSize, windowConstant)
```

You get this nice binary image:

[image]

Now, as you can see, the image has some blob noise. Let’s apply an `area filter` to get rid of the noise. The noise is smaller than the target blobs of interest, so we can easy filter them based on area, like this:

```
# Perform an area filter on the binary blobs:
componentsNumber, labeledImage, componentStats, componentCentroids = \
cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binaryImage, connectivity=4)

# Set the minimum pixels for the area filter:
minArea = 20

# Get the indices/labels of the remaining components based on the area stat
# (skip the background component at index 0)
remainingComponentLabels = [i for i in range(1, componentsNumber) if componentStats[i][4] >= minArea]

# Filter the labeled pixels based on the remaining labels,
# assign pixel intensity to 255 (uint8) for the remaining pixels
filteredImage = np.where(np.isin(labeledImage, remainingComponentLabels) == True, 255, 0).astype('uint8')
```

This is the filtered image:

[image]

We can improve the quality of this image with some morphology. Some of the characters seem to be broken (Check out the first `3` - it is broken in two separated blobs). We can join them applying a closing operation:

```
# Set kernel (structuring element) size:
kernelSize = 3

# Set operation iterations:
opIterations = 1

# Get the structuring element:
maxKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))

# Perform closing:
closingImage = cv2.morphologyEx(filteredImage, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, maxKernel, None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)
```

This is the "closed" image:

[image]

Now, you want to get the `bounding boxes` for each character. Let’s detect the outer contour of each blob and fit a nice rectangle around it:

```
# Get each bounding box
# Find the big contours/blobs on the filtered image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closingImage, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contours_poly = [None] * len(contours)
# The Bounding Rectangles will be stored here:
boundRect = []

# Alright, just look for the outer bounding boxes:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):

    if hierarchy[0][i][3] == -1:
        contours_poly[i] = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
        boundRect.append(cv2.boundingRect(contours_poly[i]))


# Draw the bounding boxes on the (copied) input image:
for i in range(len(boundRect)):
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    cv2.rectangle(inputCopy, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
              (int(boundRect[i][0] + boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1] + boundRect[i][3])), color, 2)
```

The last `for` loop is pretty much optional. It fetches each bounding rectangle from the list and draws it on the input image, so you can see each individual rectangle, like this:

[image]

Let's visualize that on the binary image:

[image]

Additionally, if you want to crop each character using the bounding boxes we just got, you do it like this:

```
# Crop the characters:
for i in range(len(boundRect)):
    # Get the roi for each bounding rectangle:
    x, y, w, h = boundRect[i]

    # Crop the roi:
    croppedImg = closingImage[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cv2.imshow("Cropped Character: "+str(i), croppedImg)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is how you can get the individual bounding boxes. Now, maybe you are trying to pass these images to an `OCR`. I tried passing the **filtered binary image** (after the closing operation) to `pyocr` (That’s the OCR I’m using) and I get this as output string: `31197402`

The code I used to get the `OCR` of the closed image is this:

```
# Set the OCR libraries:
from PIL import Image
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders

# Set pyocr tools:
tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
# The tools are returned in the recommended order of usage
tool = tools[0]

# Set OCR language:
langs = tool.get_available_languages()
lang = langs[0]

# Get string from image:
txt = tool.image_to_string(
    Image.open(path + "closingImage.png"),
    lang=lang,
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder()
)

print("Text is:"+txt)
```

Be aware that the `OCR` receives black characters on white background, so you must invert the image first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply (again) :). Your method works great, but the problem is, that it needs too much manual information. I need something that automatically can read the numbers without any manual preprocessing. I was thinking of an algorithm to at least find the correct bounding boxes, so that I can train a neural network on the task (sort of like MNIST). Do you know of any possibilities here?

Comment: @spadel I'm sorry, the requirements in your question didn't mention a fully automatic solution. You asked for bounding boxes for the digits and I provided just that. Maybe try posting a new question and ask for a deep learning-based only answer and see if any suggestion comes up. Good luck, my friend.

Comment: I was hoping to find an algorithm, which could be applied universally with minimum adjustments. In fact, when iterating over the manual input data which your approach I achieve quite good results. But it's also computationally expensive. I marked your answer as solution anyways, since it is the best, that I have so far :) so thanks again!