# How to improve PyTesseract OCR Accuracy?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract, text-recognition

I am trying to improve the accuracy of an OCR I wrote. It performs well for a normal image but struggles for a noisy image.

The noisy image:

[image]

I wrote a function to remove the noise and it does remove a lot of the noise present but also diminishes the text a bit. I am only able to capture around 60% of the text. I tried adjusting the contrast, sharpness and threshold but not able to improve OCR performance.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

def noise_remove(image):
    kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
    image = cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations=1)
    kernel = np.ones((1,1), np.uint8)
    image = cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations=1)
    image = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    image = cv2.medianBlur(image, 3)
    return image

img = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
img  = cv2.resize(img, None, fx = 0.8, fy = 0.8)
blurImg = noise_remove(img)
hImg, wImg, _ = img.shape
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(blurImg)
print(text)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The output I get:

[image]

Result:

> Little: afr aid its eat looked now. iy ye lady girl them good me make. It hardly
> cousin ime always. fin shortiy village is raising we sheiting replied. She the ~
> tavourabdle partiality inhabiting travelling impression pub luo. His six are
> entreaties instrument acceptance unsatiable her. Athongs} as or on herself chapter
> ertered carried no Sold oid ten are quit lose deal his sent. You correct how sex
> several far distant believe journey parties. We shyniss enquire uncivil attied if
> carried to A

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65738928/bounding-box-detection-for-characters-digits/65744674#65744674

Comment: this is too much filtering, or the wrong filtering.